# Swap CTRL with CAPSLOCK in Windows only for emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, keyboard-layout

I was able to remap CTRL and CAPS LOCK keys with each other using registry editor in Windows. It is pretty convenient now in emacs but quite awkward for the normal applications.

I'd like to remap CTRL <-> CAPS only for emacs but for everything else, the keys should remain the same. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible with an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script like the following:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#IfWinActive, Emacs
Capslock::Ctrl
Ctrl::Capslock
#IfWinActive
```

See [SetTitleMatchMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm), [#IfWinActive / #IfWinExist](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm), [Remapping Keys and Buttons](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) and other AHK docs if you need to tweak the script (especially to match the Emacs window title or *ahk_class* properly).